# Mixing MVC 5 + WEB API 2 Authentication for Website & Mobile App

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I just got Visual Studio 2013 loaded up and want to create a new web/mobile app that uses the same authentication for the website version and the mobile version.

I loaded up both templates (MVC5 w/Indivual Account & WEB API w/Individual Account) to check them out but it looks like I actually want to do a merge of those projects so the MVC5 uses the Web Api 2 OWIN for normal username & password authentication along with Social Media logins via Oauth.

SPA - I did look at this template but I'm not looking for a SPA as my website will need to be SEO friendly plus I know MVC and want to keep using it.

This would seem like an obvious template that developers would like to have in order to support both websites and mobile apps in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is to share user accounts between the MVC app and the Web Api app, then all you need to do is to have them both point to the same `UserStore`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/